# How to create multiple data frames & write it to excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, export-to-excel

I have two data frames and joined the data with left join from the column "country"

i need to create a separate table in excel for each 4 countries from the joined dataframes as per the attached format.

Please advise how can i achieve this ?

[image]please advise how can i achieve this?

```
Import Pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file = pd.ExcelFile(r"p:\test\sample.xlsx")
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, 'sample1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file, 'sample2')
df3 = (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='country', right_on='Country', how='left').drop.('amount', axis=1))
n = len(pd.unique(df3['country']))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on `df3['Country'].unique()`:

```
for country in df3['Country'].unique():
   df_ = df3[df3['Country'] == country].to_excel(f'path_to_output_{country}.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

How can i write the unique dataframes in excel side by side.

Ex: First four should be in one row and the next row should be other four. Each row should be four data frames only ( Total unique data frames / 4).

Please advise..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.groupby`:

```py
for country, g in df.groupby("country"):
    g.to_excel(f"file_{country}.xls", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

How can i write the unique dataframes in excel side by side.

Ex: First four should be in one row and the next row should be other four. Each row should be four data frames only ( Total unique data frames / 4).

Please advise..

Comment: @Ramesh Please update your question with sample data (as text) and expected output.

Comment: From the data frame, if county unique count is more than 4, then i need to separate for each 4 country and write it in the excel .

I want to write data in excel like below output:


Afghanistan Albania Algeria Angola
2011 2011 2011 2011
2012 2012 2012 2012
2013 2013 2013 2013

Argentina Armenia Australia Austria
2011 2011 2011 2011
2012 2012 2012 2012
2013 2013 2013 2013


Bahrain Bangladesh Belarus Belgium
2011 2011 2011 2011
2012 2012 2012 2012
2013 2013 2013 2013


Belize Bolivia
2011 2011
2012 2012
2013 2013